Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled automatically after system reboot
I have recently installed Ubuntu 22 alongside Windows 10; it is dual boot. My Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled after this. After some online research I have disabled the device (Realtek 802.11 adapter) and enabled it again and then rebooted the system, this fixes the issue and enables the Wi-Fi. But if i go to Ubuntu in dual boot and then come back to Windows the Wi-Fi adapter gets disabled again. Also, system is taking more than usual time to boot into Windows. So, I must enable the device manually every time I boot to Ubuntu.
How do I fix this?

There a few things that can become a bit problematic within a dual boot configuration.  You might want to try to disable Fast Startup in your Windows 10 operating system and see if that resolves the problem.

Does the adapter work in ubuntu?

@Run5k already try that with no luck

@SaaranshGarg it is working smoothly in ubuntu

It isn't clear what happens. Does the WiFi shows as disabled in Windows, Ubuntu or both (when alternating OSes)? Some devices, namely WiFi, being 'hijacked' by a semi-hibernated Windows (the result of Fast Startup) is a know issue. That's why we say disabling Fast Startup is a must when dual-booting (and I suspect you didn't disabled it properly). Now, if the same happens in Windows after Ubuntu that's a symptom of a deeper problem. As always, update UEFI and even if that doesn't solve it, next try to shutdown instead of reboot.

@ChanganAuto sorry for the confusion. No issues at all with ubuntu. Fast statup is unticked and did not use hibernate

No issues at all with ubuntu. Still doesn't clarify what needs to be clarified. In what direction them problem happens? Booting Ubuntu after Windows or booting Windows after Ubuntu? Does the same happens if you shutdown instead of rebooting? Have you updated UEFI already? If not, why not?
